# Multiple calls with mule to ODATA server to retrieve tables

Tags: mulesoft

I have to retrieve 20 tables from ODATA service with mule 3. The solution that I have created is using scatter gather to make these http request calls and the fetched payload is saved into files.

It works fine only it look not very elegant, because you see scatter gather with a lot of http request connectors. There is no ODATA connector for 3.9 mule and Foreach was not possible to loop into the calls. Do you guys have any idea how to solve it with less connectors or logic?

```
    <flow name="proces-flow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="30000"/>
            <logger message="start flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </poll>
        <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="${http.cat.path}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="${http.sub.path}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="${http.sub2.path}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="${http.sub3.path}" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" protocol="HTTPS" host="caller-test.service.com" port="443" basePath="/repo/v1/odata/Incidents?$filter=callDate gt 2019-09-01T08:00:00Z and callDate lt 2019-09-01T09:00:00Z" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
        </scatter-gather>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Local\fileshare-service" outputPattern="output.json" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <exception-strategy ref="" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
    </flow>
```

As you can see if I have to make 20 queries I have to add 20 calls. Because it's a ODATA I use the base path to add the hole query in it.

This works but, as I say, it's not the solution you want if the application will grow. For those how have query inside the request I have to create new http request configuration every time, because I use the base path to add variable etc and that can't be done in usual path.

Comment: Please share the relevant configurations and flows to understand what it is currently doing, anonimizing the confidential information like credentials.

Comment: @aled I have added the interface section above, thanks